# Connecting Multiple blueprints Clients to Neo4j Remote Server

Tags: neo4j, tinkerpop

I am trying to do a simple test on neo4j database reading response time.

I have used blueprints API to connect to my neo4j instance and created my client using this code

```
Map<String, String> configuration = new HashMap<String, String>();
configuration.put("ha.machine_id", "1");
configuration.put("ha.server", "localhost:6001");
graph = new Neo4jHaGraph("/tmp/my_graph2", configuration);
```

When I use this code to run a single thread it works fine, however creating more than one thread throws lock error.

This makes me think that its trying to start in embedded mode. not sure why?

Is there a way to tell blueprints API to remotely connect to neo4j server instead of loading the graph in embedded mode?

Looking at this SO thread - [Using Neo4j embedded in Java for a remote DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461574/using-neo4j-embedded-in-java-for-a-remote-db)

It seems REST is the only way (in neo4j) to achieve multiple clients, however I would like to know if we can achieve this using blueprints client api.